How to Make New Class Method Work Python 3.11.4?
I have created a subclass called list that inherits list. I have managed to create .push() as it is in Javascript, however when I made push it did not show up as a method.
I tried this:
class list(list):
    def push(self,element):
        list.append(element)
        l=len(self)
        return l

    
    
    
    def pop(self):
        x=self[len(self)-1]
        list.remove(x)
        return x
array=[0,1,2,3,4]
print(array.pop())
print(array.push(4))

Which got me:
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\default.n100-cottage\Downloads\Code\Python\Class-Testing.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(array.push(4))
          ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'push'

I also tried:
class list(list):
    def push(self,element):
        list.append(element)
        return len(list)

    
    
    
    def pop(self):
        x=self[len(self)-1]
        list.remove(x)
        return x
array=[0,1,2,3,4]
print(array.pop())
print(array.push(4))

Which got me:
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\default.n100-cottage\Downloads\Code\Python\Class-Testing.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(array.push(4))
          ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'push'

Thanks in advance for any help you might render.

[0,1,2,3,4] created an instance of the standard, built-in list object.  Nothing you can possibly do in Python code will change that fact; you have to explicitly create an instance of your replacement class: list([0,1,2,3,4]) perhaps (although naming yours the same as the built-in is just going to cause confusion).

Thank you @jasonharper. Could you please explain why the array had the method .pop() but not .push().

The standard list has a .pop() method, that's what got called there, not your method.

Thanks a lot. I didn't realize it had a .pop() method.
